# Can't reset Chef user's key or password "missing update permission"

Tags: linux, centos, chef-infra

Running Chef 12.5
CentOS Linux release 7.2.1511 (Core)

I created a new Chef user with these commands:

```
chef-server-ctl user-create test firstname lastname email@fake.com 'Passw0rd1!'
chef-server-ctl org-user-add myorg test
```

Added the user to the "users" group

Now in the GUI if I try to reset the user's key or password I get this error:
[image]

My account is an admin.

How do I reset a this user's password and key?

OK so I can login as the user and reset its key. But why can't an admin do that? I thought Chef admins had access to Delete,Grant,Read,Update all Chef objects?

Comment: Anything preventing the user from logging in and resetting their own key?

Comment: Just because it generate a **private** key which as the name implies should be private and only accessible to the user himself. As this key identify every action the user will do, everything should be in place to avoid impersonation by anyone else, including admins.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a user has lost their password you can change it via command line on the server with an admin user.

`chef-server-ctl password test`

This will prompt you to enter and confirm a new password. Give this to your user and let them manage their own key and password.